# Is there any way to protect the password in remmina?

Tags: kubuntu, password, remote-desktop, remote-access, remmina

Is there any way to protect the password stored in remmina so that i would not be able to get the password using DES3?

I use kubuntu 18

i used the following code to decrypt the password and it worked.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import DES3

REMMINAPREF_SECRET_B64=b'<STRING FROM remmina.prefs>'

passw = "<STRING FROM XXXXXXX.remmina>"
passw = base64.b64decode(passw)
secret = base64.b64decode(REMMINAPREF_SECRET_B64)
key = secret[:24]
iv = secret[24:]
cipher = DES3.new(key, DES3.MODE_CBC, iv)
result = cipher.decrypt(passw)
result = result.decode('utf-8')

print(result)
```

is there any way to protect it so that a code like this one would not be able to extract the password?

Comment: No, and why should it? The protection of this is based on the SECRET not being visible beyond the user and the admin of that system. If someone other than those 2 can read the secret you got a very big security problem.  Try to do this from a 2nd user you create. It will error out on permissions. What are the permissons of `XXXXXXX.remmina`? Should be 400 or 600 (`r-- --- ---` or `rw- --- ---`)

Comment: Thank you very much! both of the files are -r--------
Is there any way maybe to disable password saving in remmina ?

Comment: It is listed as a feature but I have not seen where to do this. Do you know of a .conf file for remmina? Would be the 1st place to look for a setting

Comment: i tried looking for a conf file but i can't find it :/ 
the only thing i see it this :
/root/.config/remmina
/root/.config/remmina/remmina.pref